# Why does my agent always takes a same action in DQN - Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, policy-gradient-descent

I have trained an RL agent using DQN algorithm. After 20000 episodes my rewards are converged. Now when I test this agent, the agent is always taking the same action , irrespective of state. I find this very weird. Can someone help me with this. Is there a reason, anyone can think of why is the agent behaving this way?

Reward plot

[image]

When I test the agent

```
state = env.reset()
print('State: ', state)

state_encod = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])
q_values = model.predict(state_encod)
action_key = np.argmax(q_values)
print(action_key)
print(index_to_action_mapping[action_key])
print(q_values[0][0])
print(q_values[0][action_key])

q_values_plotting = []
for i in range(0,action_size):
    q_values_plotting.append(q_values[0][i])


plt.plot(np.arange(0,action_size),q_values_plotting)
```

Every time it gives the same q_values plot, even though state initialized is different every time.Below is the q_Value plot.

[image]

Testing:

code

```
test_rewards = []
for episode in range(1000):
    terminal_state = False
    state = env.reset()
    episode_reward = 0
    while terminal_state == False:
        print('State: ', state)
        state_encod = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])
        q_values = model.predict(state_encod)
        action_key = np.argmax(q_values)
        action = index_to_action_mapping[action_key]
        print('Action: ', action)
        next_state, reward, terminal_state = env.step(state, action)
        print('Next_state: ', next_state)
        print('Reward: ', reward)
        print('Terminal_state: ', terminal_state, '\n')
        print('----------------------------')
        episode_reward += reward
        state = deepcopy(next_state)
    print('Episode Reward' + str(episode_reward))
    test_rewards.append(episode_reward)

plt.plot(test_rewards)
```

[image]

Thanks.

Adding environment

```
import gym
import rom_vav_150mm_polyreg as rom
import numpy as np
import random

class VAVenv(gym.Env):

    def __init__(self):
        # Zone temperature set point and limits
        self.temp_sp = 24
        self.temp_sp_max = 24.5
        self.temp_sp_min = 23.7

        # no; of hours in an episode and time interval for each step
        self.MAXSTEPS = 11
        self.time_interval = 5./60. #in hrs

        # constants
        self.zone_volume = 775


    def step(self,state,action):

        # state -> Time, Volume, Load, SAT ,RAT
        # action -> CFM

        action_cfm = action[0]

#        damper_opening = state[2]
        load = state[2]
        sat = state[3]
        current_temp = state[4]

        #input
        inputs_rat = np.array([load,action_cfm, self.zone_volume,current_temp,sat])

        '''
        AFTER 5 MINUTES
        '''
        #output
        output = [self.KStep + self.time_interval,self.zone_volume,rom.load(self.KStep + self.time_interval),
                  sat,rom.rat(inputs_rat)]


        #reward calculation
        thermal_coefficient = -0.1

        zone_temperature = output[4]

        if zone_temperature < self.temp_sp_min:
            temp_penalty = self.temp_sp_min - zone_temperature
        elif zone_temperature > self.temp_sp_max:
            temp_penalty = zone_temperature - self.temp_sp_max
        else :
            temp_penalty = -10

        reward = thermal_coefficient * temp_penalty

        # create next step
        next_state = np.array(output)

        # increment simulation step count
        self.KStep += self.time_interval

        # done - end of one episode, when kSteps reaches the maximum steps in an episode
        done = False
        if self.KStep > self.MAXSTEPS:
            done = True


        return next_state,reward,done


    def reset(self):
        self.KStep = 0

        # initialize all the values of a state
        initial_rat = random.uniform(23,27)
        initial_sat = random.uniform(12,14)
        # return a state
        return np.array([self.KStep,self.zone_volume,
                         rom.load(self.KStep),initial_sat,initial_rat])
```

Comment: Assuming your code doesn't have any bug, the problem could be related with how is you reward designed. So, could you please share more info about the environment and the reward?

Comment: The simple explanation is that DQN learns one of the actions gets larger reward, and as a result it always selects that action. Detailed answer needs some knowledge of the environment.

Comment: @cvg Dear friend, did you solve your problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: @FatemehKarimi did you solve the issue? Even I have the same issue :)

Comment: @KnownUnknown I did not. sorry :((